# IF Statement to return a value based on two cells in sheets/excel with colour formatting

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, excel-formula

Hi I'm struggling with the correct IF statement to look at the impact and effort columns and assign the correct category Value with colour which I will need to copy through a massive list. Just cant seem to get it right and on a couple of deadlines.

[image: Example Snip]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use in C2:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2:A&B2:B, {F2:F&E2:E, G2:G}, 2, 0)))
```